# Simple Terrain Grid (not working)

Tags: terrain-rendering, directx11

I know yall are probably going to hate me.....but I can't figure out what im doing wrong, im trying to make a SIMPLE Vertex Grid (for Terrain) but I get a black screen for some reason And I can't figure out why. It does run, but I just get a black screen afterwards....I hate posting such huge code on this site but I figure if anyone can explain what the heck I did wrong i'd be able to understand a little bit better.

I think the problem....may be in the matrix, but my code is simple and im 100% sure im doing the Grid right because I took it from a working tutorial that does grids (but it's large and VERY confusing for a beginner, so I just took the appropriate code).

I know it's alot to look at (vars.h is very small) and main.cpp is pretty small too but I know it's still alot.....but im just completely stuck.

vars.h
http://pastebin.com/SupcqB8N

main.cpp
http://pastebin.com/vAnSUTpp

shaders.hlsl

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer
{
    float4x4 matFinal;
}

struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = mul(matFinal, position);
    output.color = color;

    return output;
}


float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried building up from example code you know works? Incrementally adding to it? I think that's your best solution. Start with drawing a triangle and make sure that shows up, then add textures, then make it two triangles drawn from a loop, then make it into your whole grid.

For your current code, I can only suggest the basic 3D troubleshooting stuff.

- Make sure your camera is pointing the right direction
- Disable lighting, depth buffer, clipping, textures and special effects
- Check that your objects are properly formed
- Make sure your camera has it's bounds set up correctly

  Good luck!

Comment: +1 When implementing something grand, taking incremental steps from something tiny is always incredibly helpful. In every single step, you have only a tiny amount of code that might not be working, so identifying any problems that appear in each step is easy.